# Matrix Vector Multiplication in C++

Tags: c++, vector, matrix

I've a code to multiply matrix and a vector. But, it doesn't **enter inside the** `for` loop in the friend function `calc()`. Can you spot the error?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class vector;
class matrix
{
public:
    int r,c,ma[10][10];
    void get(int r, int c=3)
    {
        int i,j;
        cout<<"Enter the matrix elements\n";
        for(i=0; i<r; i++)
            for(j=0; j<c; j++)
            {
                cin>>ma[i][j];
            }
        cout<<"Your input: ";
        for(i=0; i<r; i++)
        {
            cout<<"\n";
            for(j=0; j<c; j++)
            {
                cout<<ma[i][j]<<"\t";
            }
        }
    }
    friend void calc(matrix m,vector v);
};

class vector
{
public:
    int val,va[10];
    void get(int v=3)
    {
        int i;
        cout<<"\nEnter the vector values\n";
        for(i=0; i<v; i++)
        {
            cin>>va[i];
        }
        cout<<"\nYour input:\n";
        for(i=0; i<v; i++)
        {
            cout<<va[i]<<"\t";
        }
    }
    friend void calc(matrix m,vector v);
};

void calc(matrix m,vector v)
{
    int c[10],i,j;
    if(m.c == v.val)
    {
        for(i=0; i<v.val; i++)
        {
            cout<<"Entered 1st loop";
            c[i] = 0;
            for(j=0; j<m.r; j++)
            {
                c[i] = c[i]+(m.ma[i][j] * v.va[j]);
            }
        }
    }
    cout<<"\nThe result is :\n";
    for(i=0; i<m.r; i++)
    {
        cout<<"Entered for";
        cout<<"\n"<<c[i];
    }
}

int main()
{
    int r;
    matrix m1;
    vector v1;
    cout<<"Enter the number of rows = ";
    cin>>r;
    m1.get(r);
    v1.get();
    calc(m1,v1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger, step through the code. See what the values are when it fails to enter the for loop, and why.

Comment: You don't initialise some of the class member variables.

Comment: I dunno what debugger you were using, but mine doesn't require "output codes." It is somewhat the point of the debugger, so you don't *have* to sprinkle junk in your code if you don't want to. And, having a homegrown class named `vector` without its own namespace *after* activating `using namespace std;` is eventually going to bite you in the arse.

Comment: @Haroogan I'm afraid you're right.

Answer (score 4):

You never initialize `val` in `vector` class, neither you do `r` and `c` in `matrix` class. Therefore, the check `if(m.c == v.val)` can never pass simply because the values of these members are **undefined** (contain random garbage).

I recommend that you have a look at **[The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)**; a good book will help you grasp the basics.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
#include<windows.h>
using namespace std;
class vecter;
class matrix
{
    int matrex[3][3];
public:

    friend void multiply(matrix &,vecter &);
    void setmatrix()
    {
       cout<<"Enter the elements into the matrix array "<<endl;
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
            {
                for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
                {
                    cout<<"Enter the element in to the "<<i+1<<" row and "<<j+1<<" coloumn "<<endl;
                    cin>>matrex[i][j];
                }
            }
    }
    void dismatrix()
    {
       cout<<" The elements into the matrix array are "<<endl;
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
            {
                cout<<"|";
                for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
                {
                    cout<<":"<<matrex[i][j]<<" : ";
                }
                cout<<"|";
                cout<<endl;
            }
    }
};
class vecter
{
    int vector[3];
public:

    friend void multiply(matrix &,vecter &);
    void setvector()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        {   cout<<"Enter the "<<i+1<<" element in to the vector Array "<<endl;
            cin>>vector[i];
        }
    }

    void disvector()
    {
        cout<<"The elements in the index of the vector array are "<<endl;
        for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            cout<<"|"<<vector[i]<<"|"<<endl;
        }

    }
};
void multiply (matrix &m,vecter &v)
{
    int solution[3];
    //initilization.
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        solution[i]=0;
    }
    //multiplication.
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
        {

             solution[i]+=( m.matrex[i][j]*v.vector[j]);
        }

    }
    cout<<"\t\t\t\t\t processing..... ";
        for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
        {
            cout<<char(219);
            Sleep(200);    
        }
        cout<<endl;
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            cout<<"|"<<solution[i]<<"|"<<endl;
        }

}
int main()
{
    matrix m;
    vecter v;
    v.setvector();
    m.setmatrix();
    m.dismatrix();
    cout<<endl;
    v.disvector();
    multiply(m,v);
    system ("pause>0");

}
```

Comment: You should try to use this method it is easy to understand and display a perfect result for the 3*3 matrix and 1*3 vector column.